# CSP connect-src network sources

Tags: content-security-policy

We are trying to implement CSP in our application. But we are stuck for the following situation:

We are using the Epson EPOS SDK script, which connects to the local IP of the printer of our users. That IP is different (of course) for every user, and we can't add all hosts in the `connect-src` line.

I have tried to generate a hash of the specific code but I can't get that code. The SDK (which is loaded as 'epos.js') is sending an POST with the commands to the printer. When I send that command in PostMan I only get an response (XML) from the printer and not the script.

Now I'm looking for other ways to use CSP in combination with this SDK. Of course I can add an * as `connect-src` but that will be the same as not using CSP. Is there a way to accept connections to local IP addresses? Or are there better ways to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `connect-src` directive does not support hash-sources, it's road to nowhere.

CSP level 3 [does not allow](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#match-hosts) to use IPv4address (except 127.0.0.1) as host-sourses, although browsers support them (Chrome and Firefox was tested). Therefore, it is incorrect to use this feature in production.

The only way is `connect-src *;`, i do not see any workarounds.

Comment: Thnx, an hash at ```connect-src``` can not work indeed, since it only allows hosts and not scripts. We now used the *, not the safest option but it's the only option which will work in our case.